# hibernate ResultSet

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Добрый день, при старте веб проекта вылетает ошибка

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1682)
org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
ua.dao.UserDaoImpl.list(UserDaoImpl.java:36)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.list(Unknown Source)
ua.controller.HomeController.handleRequest(HomeController.java:31)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:177)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: колонка this_.id не существует
 Позиция: 8
  org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1682)
org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
ua.dao.UserDaoImpl.list(UserDaoImpl.java:36)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.list(Unknown Source)
ua.controller.HomeController.handleRequest(HomeController.java:31)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:177)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

судя по тому что здесь написано хибернейт считает, что в таблице нет колонки id, что довольно странно:

```
CREATE TABLE
USER
(
    id BIGINT DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    first_name CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    second_name CHARACTER VARYING(255),
    last_name CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    is_active BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    registration_date TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    password TEXT NOT NULL,
    email CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (email)
);
```

Юзер:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "second_name")
private String secondName;
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "is_active")
private boolean isActive;
@Column(name = "registration_date")
private Timestamp registrationDate;
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
//геттеры сеттеры.
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не так делаю. Спасибо!

Comment: Извиняюсь, вопрос уже решил. Проблема была в том, что в postgre таблица user есть своя, и я когда ты создаешь новую, то  обращаться к ней приходится как public.user.  @Table(name = "public.user"). Тему можно закривать